Using tell with a gzip file in TCL
When I use zlib push gunzip, to read a large gzip file line by line, the tell function always returns -1 instead of the current access position.  Is there a way to get the access position while reading a gzip file line by line?
set fp [open "foo.gz" r]
zlib push gunzip $fp
while {![eof $fp]} {
    set line [gets $fp]
    set idx [tell $fp]
    puts $idx
}

$idx is always -1

I believe that tell is incompatible with zlib push in this case as zlib push is applying a transformation to the data, which won't be visible to tell. https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/zlib.htm#M26 What is your actual goal here and maybe we can find you a solution?

I have an extremely large gzip data file that is in the format:
NET 

NET 

...
When I see the keyword NET, I wanted to use tell get the location in the channel.  If I see an error in the data, I add that location to a list.  After going through the file, I was going to use a separate function using seek, to print out the NET  and lines of data of the fails into an output file.

If you use regular string commands instead of tell, it will work fine with the zlib push and gets that you are using. E.g. if {[string first "NET" $line] != "-1"} {...}

Not many compression algorithms support seeking to random spots in a stream of compressed data.

There isn't an efficient way to produce a relation between the uncompressed index, the related compressed index, and the decompressor state at that point, not even on a per-kilobyte basis. Yes, the decompressor knows the offset into the compressed data, but that doesn't correspond an uncompressed index (it's kind of the point that one compressed byte can be many uncompressed ones) and without the decompressor stat you could never seek anyway. (tell is and always was actually just a seek with a relative offset of zero.) The only way we could seek to an arbitrary location would be to rewind to the start and just read the data out of the stream until we'd gone far enough, and the point of doing a seek is typically to avoid that.
In short, the channel filter that implements the gunzip support simply does not provide any support for seek (and tell as a special case of that) and there isn't a clear way to write such an implementation without it being crazy expensive.
